# Jquery - set class “active” in Li with cookie II

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I really do not know where is the mistake. Still it doesn't work with cookie when I refresh page.

Function: If I click on "LI" then "LI" have class "active". If I reloading page "LI" have still class "active".

http://jsfiddle.net/skyndas/arfqxc6e/

```
function setPatCookie() {
        PatCookieVal = $('.patchange li').hasClass('active') ? 'isActive' : 'notActive';
        $.cookie('PatCookieName', PatCookieVal, {
            expires: 365,
            path: '/'
        });    
    }

    $(".patchange li").click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        setPatCookie();
    });

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('PatCookieName') == 'isActive') {
            $('.patchange li').addClass('active');    
        } else {
            $('.patchange li').removeClass('active');
        }  
});
```

Please help me. Thanks

Solution:

```
<UL CLASS="patchange">
  <LI ID="pat_1" CLASS='patchange_1' TITLE="">1</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_2" CLASS='patchange_2' TITLE="">2</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_3" CLASS='patchange_3' TITLE="">3</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_4" CLASS='patchange_4' TITLE="">4</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_5" CLASS='patchange_5' TITLE="">5</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_6" CLASS='patchange_6' TITLE="">6</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_7" CLASS='patchange_7' TITLE="">7</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_8" CLASS='patchange_8' TITLE="">8</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_9" CLASS='patchange_9' TITLE="">9</LI>
  <LI ID="pat_10" CLASS='patchange_10' TITLE="">10</LI>
</UL>
```

Jquery

```
$(".patchange li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $.cookie('PatCookieName', $(this).attr('id'), {
        expires: 365,
        path: '/'
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    /* Cookie - isActive/notActive */
    $('#' + $.cookie("PatCookieName")).addClass('active');
});
```

Thanks for idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add different `id`'s to each `li`, save the id of the selected one on the cookie rather than a boolean and restore it if present when browsing back.